# Restangular promises Angular

Tags: angularjs, promise

Я делаю небольшое приложение, где пользователь может добавить, изменить, просмотреть и удалить объект. Все данные хранятся в JSON файле. Когда я что-то делаю с объектами, для перезаписи использую php-код. Там все норм.

Удаление и просмотр работают без проблем. Проблемы с добавлением/редактированием.

Итак, как оно работает. На основной странице отображаются все объекты, у каждого из них есть свой набор кнопок (посмотреть, изменить, удалить), и есть кнопка Создать новый объект, после клика на которую пользователя отправляют на другую форму с текстовыми полями. После заполнения полей пользователь нажимает кнопку Создать. В результате новый объект записывается в JSON, и пользователь снова попадает на страницу со списком всех объектов. НО. Там отображается старый список, без вновь добавленного. То же самое происходит при изменении объекта: в JSON'е изменения сохранены, а в браузере изменений никаких.

Насколько я понимаю, вся беда в promise'ах, вернее в том, что я не умею ими пользоваться, скорее всего. Поскольку это дело асинхронное, код не успевает сделать то, что мне надо, а я не могу ему объяснить, что за чем нужно делать. Видимо, у меня отображение в браузер срабатывает быстрее, чем заканчивается запись в JSON. Я не первый день пытаюсь понять, как оно должно быть, перепробовала кучу способов, но ни один пока не помог.

Вот мои контроллеры

```
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, customers, ListService) {
   $scope.customers = customers;
   cust = customers;
   $scope.removeItem = function removeItem(index) {
      $scope.customers.splice(index, 1);
      ListService.saveData($scope.customers);
  };
});

app.controller('CreateController', function ($scope, customers, ListService) {

  $scope.customers = customers;
  $scope.createItem = function createItem(item) {
      $scope.customers = customers;
      $scope.customers.push(item);
      ListService.saveData($scope.customers);
  };
});

app.controller('UpdateController', function ($scope, details, ListService) {
  $scope.item = details[0];
  var keep = {};
  for (var key in details[0]) {
      keep[key] = details[0][key];
  }

  $scope.updateItem = function updateItem() {
      $scope.customers = cust;
      var ind = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) {
          if (($scope.customers[i].id == keep.id)) {
              ind = i;
          }
      }
     if (ind != -1) {
          $scope.customers.splice(ind, 1, $scope.item);
      }
      ListService.saveData($scope.customers);
  };
});
```

Вот сервис

```
.service('ListService', function(Restangular) {

this.getCustomers = function() {
    return Restangular.all("./file.json").getList().then( function(res) {
        return res;
    });
};

this.saveData = function (dbs) {
    return Restangular.oneUrl("./file.json", '/file.php').customPOST(dbs, undefined, undefined, { 'Content-Type': "application/json" });
};

this.getDetails = function(itemId) {
    var examples = Restangular.all('./file.json');
    return examples.getList().then(function(data) {
        var d = data;
        return d.filter(function (item) {
        if (item.id == itemId) {
            return item;
        }
        });
    });
};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Promise сохраняют состояние. Нельзя использовать один и тот же Promise не пересоздав его.

Comment: можете пояснить подробнее? что нужно исправить (или переписать)?

Comment: `ListService.saveData($scope.customers).then(function () { // тут переход на страницу })`

Comment: return Restangular.all("./file.json").getList().then( function(res) {
    return res;
 });   данная запись имеет тот же смысл, что return Restangular.all("./file.json").getList()

Comment: в случае с return Restangular.all("./file.json").getList().then( function(res) { return res; }); согласна, там я просто все подряд стала пробовать, лишь бы заработало, а вот по поводу ListService.saveData($scope.customers).then(function () { // тут переход на страницу }) не совсем поняла.